# How to add a new field to magento configuration?

Tags: php, magento, configuration

I need to add a new filed to magento configuration in the back-end, under the Catalog -> Product Alerts after the 'Alert Email Sender' (at last). Can anybody give the XML for this ?

Answer (score 1):

you can put this code to your module system.xml

```
        <catalog>
            <groups>
                <productalert>
                    <fields>
                        <test_field translate="label">
                            <label>some text</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </test_field>
                    </fields>
                </productalert>
            </groups>
        </catalog>
```

All simple system.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <catalog>
            <groups>
                <productalert>
                    <fields>
                        <test_field translate="label">
                            <label>some text</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </test_field>
                    </fields>
                </productalert>
            </groups>
        </catalog>
    </sections>
</config>
```

result - 
[image: new field]